# Difference between BezierBy and BezierTo in Cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

I Want to know the difference between the BezierBy and BezierTo. What will happen in the below code if say this is the scenario

```
     CCBezierConfig bezier = new CCBezierConfig();


     // Bezier curve  
     bezier.controlPoint_1 = CGPoint.make(1002.0f,475.0f);
     bezier.controlPoint_2 = CGPoint.make(454.0f, 281.0f);
     bezier.endPosition = CGPoint.make(-20.0f,490.0f);

     CCBezierBy by = CCBezierBy.action(100, bezier);
     CCBezierTo to = CCBezierTo.action(2, bezier);

     CCCallFuncN actionMoveDone = CCCallFuncN.action(this,"spriteMoveFinished");
     CCSequence actions = CCSequence.actions(by, actionMoveDone);

     obstacle1.runAction(actions);
```

Also have same issues in understand moveTo and moveBy

Please help me with the concepts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CCMoveTo moves your node TO position. CCMoveBy moves your node for sone pixels. All ather actions are same.
Example:

```
CCNode *a = [[CCNode alloc] init];
[a setPosition:CGPointMake(100, 100)]; //our node starts at point (100, 100)
```

now, if you'll move it **TO** CGPointMake(200,200), his positions will be (200, 200). But if you'll move it from (100, 100) **BY** CGPointMake(200,200), it will be (300, 300).

Comment: THanks dude that is what I needed, its to and by ... by - relative to the last position whereas to is the moving to the respective position ..